# How do I align the list items in an <ol> with my <p>?

Tags: css

I want exactly this to be displayed using HTML/CSS:

```
This is a paragraph.
1. This is a list item.
   Continuation of list item: using list-style-position:outside.
This is another paragraph.
```

The problem I have is that my `1.` is not lining up with `Th` (from `This` on the previous line).  This is due to an inherent `padding-left` present in the `ol`, right?  How do I get rid of this consistently across all browsers/devices?  A magic `ol { padding-left: 22px }` seems to work (on my desktop browser, but it's broken on my mobile browser), but where did this magic `22px` come from?

For your convenience, [here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/artagnon/T59Ha/17/) you can fork and write css for.

Comment: You can always override the inherent padding-left using ol{ padding-left: 0px; }

Comment: @Vivek I had the same thought, but unfortunately that conceals the list numbering as well.

Comment: Oh.. I see. In that case i think Juhana's solution will do the trick.

Comment: It does not conceal the numbering if you use `list-style-position:inside` or if you use a padding larger than 0 (say 20px) - both work and they are the proper way to deal with it.

Comment: I've created a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/T59Ha/9/). However it's a HACK `;)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a css reset/ normalize, set a custom `padding-left`, and use a meta viewport tag for mobile devices.

Comment: `1.3em` seems to be the value for IE, Firefox and Chrome on desktop, not Safari.

Comment: See [this codepen here](http://codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/nvqxe) for a solution which works.

Comment: Hm, still doesn't work properly.  The `content:` is displayed differently on different browsers (font-size).

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can specify the `font-size` on pseudo elements?

Comment: Just try it.  It's even more broken than the original solution, because there are so many more variables.

Comment: I tried Chrome, IE and Firefox, it seems OK to me on those, also: You can get periods in there: http://codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/nvqxe

Comment: There's a very simple solution, and I just found it.

Answer (score 3):

As you already mentioned, you can adjust the padding property. 
You may also need to set he list-style-position.

```
ol { list-style-position:inside; padding:0; }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DannyB/2VFnx/2/)

If, for some reason, you must use `list-style-position:outside`, then simply increase the left padding to about 20px (the distance between the number and the text) to achieve a similar result.

```
ol { list-style-position:outside; padding-left:20px; }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DannyB/2VFnx/5/)

Comment: Setting `padding` or `padding-left` to `0` doesn't respect the `padding` of the container: so if this whole thing is inside a div with a padding, the list items break out of the `div`. [Wait, I'll prepare a fiddle]

Comment: I fail to reproduce this statement. See this updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DannyB/2VFnx/2/

Comment: Oh, sorry.  I'm using `list-style-position:outside`.  Sorry about the typo in the question: I want continuation lines to line up with the text, not the number. See http://jsfiddle.net/artagnon/2VFnx/3/

Comment: So you get exactly what you pay for.... list position outside, puts the numbers outside. If you want to "push them back in", just increase the left padding value.

Comment: no... the padding you will have to give the ol is fixed. It is the distance between the number and the text of the li. Like in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DannyB/2VFnx/5/

Comment: It's not really "fixed" is it?  Is 20px some magic number? (22px seems to work slightly better).  Isn't this magic number font/resolution dependent?

Comment: @RamkumarRamachandra - The `20px` isn't a magic number, it's equal to the `padding-left` which you have set on the `div`. It makes sense to me to keep hem the same if you want to line them up.

Comment: Nope, the `padding-left` of the `div` has nothing to do with this number.  The fiddle @DannyB posted has a `div` with `padding-left` equal to `50px`.

Comment: @RamkumarRamachandra - Yes, you're right. Maybe using an `em` value will fix it then, as this is dependent on the `font-size`. Setting `padding-left: 1.3em;` fixes it in my fiddle below, and it stays aligned when I change the `font-size`.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit 2:** here is an example using `counter` instead of the default numbering. The reason is that, once you get over 9, the digits in the previous example start to break out to the left:
http://cdpn.io/izrAh

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">

p, ol {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    ol {list-style: none;}
li {
    padding-left: 30px; 
    counter-increment: nums; 
    position: relative;
}

li:before {
    content: counter(nums);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph of text.</p>
<ol>
    <li>This is a list item<br>
        Continuation of list item.
    </li>
    <li>This is a list item<br>
        Continuation of list item.
    </li>
    <li>This is a list item<br>
        Continuation of list item.
    </li>
    <li>This is a list item<br>
        Continuation of list item.
    </li>
    <li>This is a list item<br>
        Continuation of list item.
    </li>
    <li>This is a list item<br>
        Continuation of list item.
    </li>
    <li>This is a list item<br>
        Continuation of list item.
    </li>
    <li>This is a list item<br>
        Continuation of list item.
    </li>
    <li>This is a list item<br>
        Continuation of list item.
    </li>
    <li>This is a list item<br>
        Continuation of list item.
    </li>
    <li>This is a list item<br>
        Continuation of list item.
    </li>
    <li>This is a list item<br>
        Continuation of list item.
    </li>
</ol>
<p>This is a paragraph of text.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT1:** With `list-style: outside` (the default) it's easier: http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/tiALm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">

p, ol {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
ol {width: 150px}
li {margin-left: 18px;}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph of text.</p>
<ol>
    <li>This is a list item
        Continuation of list item.
    </li>
</ol>
<p>This is a paragraph of text.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

**First try:** How about something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">

p, ol {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
ol {list-style: inside; width: 150px}
li {text-indent: -16px; padding-left: 18px;}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph of text.</p>
<ol>
    <li>This is a list item
        Continuation of list item.
    </li>
</ol>
<p>This is a paragraph of text.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Notes: I've just set a small width on the `<ol>` to demonstrate the line wrapping. An alternative is to use `<br>` wherever you want line wrapping.

Comment: See what happens when I want `list-style-type: outside`? [sorry about the typo in the original question]: http://codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/lAnre

Comment: OK, I've added a second example with `list-style: outside` (which is the default, so it's not needed at all). This is actually a lot easier like this. (I should have seen that before.) I've also updated the pen.

Comment: Hm, yeah. I just noticed that, once you get over 9, the numbers extend out to the left, so I've added a third example (see top of post) that uses a completely different strategy, and works rather better (and breaks free from the 18px thing).

Comment: A slightly modified version of this is not bad: http://codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/kEhvc | However, custom values for li don't work now.

Comment: I previously updated my pen with the `list-style: none`. What custom values to you mean?

Comment: Look at the `<li value="34">` line in the fiddle I posted.

Comment: @ralph.m - You could kind of fix that using the `:after` pseudo element. `li:after {content: attr(value); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; display: block; background-color: #FFF;}`. http://codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/nvqxe.

Comment: I said "kind of" because I thought the alignment wasn't OK, but it is.  So I would call that a fix, as long as the values don't get more than 4 digits wide.

Comment: Hopeless.  The more hacks you pile on, the more variables you introduce, and the less likely it is to work on all browsers uniformly.

Answer (score 1):

If the only reason you're not using `<pre>` is that you want line wrapping:

```
p {
    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T59Ha/3/

Comment: I'm not actually using monospaced fonts (I only said that for explaining), so it's impossible to get the continuation line of the list item to line up with the previous line if I don't use a `<ol>`.  [Updated question to avoid confusion]

Comment: @RamkumarRamachandra saying that you're using monospaced fonts when you're not makes it harder, not easier, for people to come up with relevant answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look using Chrome's developer tools, you can see that the user agent style sheet sets a property with the name `-webkit-padding-start` to `40px` on the `ol`, the same is true for Firefox. Overriding this property by setting the `padding-left` to `1.3em` will line things up for you in all browsers. `1.3em` seems to always be equal to the distance between the number and the text of the `li` regardless of the `font-size` as the `em` value is calculated based on the `font-size`.

```
ol {
    list-style-position: outside;
    padding-left: 1.3em;
}
```

Here's a <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/T59Ha/18/)</kbd>

Comment: Isn't `-webkit-padding-start` dependent on lots of factors?  For me, on this browser, it's `40px`.  And what is this magic `20px` that lines everything up (`22px` works better for me)?  Is there some method to this madness?

Comment: The computed value of `1em` is dependent on the font-size. But I copied it wrongly from my browser, its actually `40px` here as well  (Latest version of Chrome). I'll fix it in the answer. Using a  [reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or [normalize](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) style sheet will help you ensure things render exactly the same across browsers.

Comment: Yes, `1em` depends on the font-size, but I don't know what that has to do with anything.  I'm already using a reset/normalize, and it works fine.  My problem is with hard-coding the magic `20px` (like I said, `22px` seems to work better for me).

Comment: I fixed up my answer to reflect what I believe actually fixes your aligning issue, setting a `font-size` based `em` value as the `padding-left` value on the `ol`.

Comment: Nope, `1.3em` is no better: still breaks on my phone's browser.

Comment: Yes, and it's not perfect on Safari on my laptop either, I think there's no other way but to figure out which `em` value works for which browsers, and then use [some browser specific hacks](http://browserhacks.com/) to get it to render right in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Without changing the CSS, you can achieve the feat with a <br/> tag as in:

```
<p>Previous paragraph</p>
<ul>
  <li>Test here<br/>
      And there</li>
</ul>
<p>Next paragraph</p>
```

To achieve it with CSS, you can look at how the <li> and <br/> are setup.

Quick note: it works with <ol> too, of course.